# TimerCallBack holding a reference

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

> Blockquote
>   TimeCallBack object references a CacheExpires object, and is on 1 of the paths from BASE_RATE_SRCE_CODEInfo[] to a GC root.

I analyzed the C# application with memory profiler and found out that surviving objects `BASE_RATE_SRCE_CODEInfo[]` are refrenced by TimerCallBack objects. These `BASE_RATE_SRCE_CODEInfo[]` objects are not being disposed by GC, Which could be the possible cause of memory leak.

So, how to remove or dispose these references `BASE_RATE_SRCE_CODEInfo[]` to TimerCallback on GC root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surviving objects that you have mentioned referencing TimerCallback objects is being used in a Timer object. Identify why Timer objects are active. It is most likely that these Timer objects are keeping your callback alive.

For better understanding of Timer Constructor (objects) visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch.aspx